# Expand 1 Text View at a time in Recycler View and collapse the expanded one when other is clicked

Tags: android

I am trying to expand and collapse the Text Views in RecyclerView and I can perform this task easily but the requirement is to expand one Text View at a time i.e. if Text View of 1st position in RecyclerView is expanded and Text View of second position is clicked then 1st one should automatically collapse.
This are the methods to expand and collapse:

```
private void addReadMore(final String text, final TextView textView) {

    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text.substring(0, 280) + "... Read More");
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            addReadLess(text, textView);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                ds.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.txt_color));
            } else {
                ds.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.txt_color));
            }
        }
    };

    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, ss.length() - 10, ss.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(ss);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}

private void addReadLess(final String text, final TextView textView) {


    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text + " Read Less");
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addReadMore(text, textView);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                ds.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.txt_color));

            } else {
                ds.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.txt_color));

            }
        }
    };
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, ss.length() - 10, ss.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(ss);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

Please suggest me how can I expand only 1 Text View at a time.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the value of the expanded index in a variable. 
And in your onClickListener where you expand the view, you call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Create a global variable ( let it be `int expandedIndex = -1`)
And everytime you call read more or read less function, update this variable and call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

**Edited**
Note: `index` is the position of the position of item in the adapter.
    int expandedIndex=-1;

```
void onBindViewHolder(){
 if(length>280 && position==-1){ //for first time, call read more } 

 else if(length<280&&position==-1){ //Call read less) } 

else { //Call read more when manual clicks are done on position }
}
private void addReadMore(final String text, final TextView textView) {
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text.substring(0, 280) + "... Read More");
}
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
position=-1;
notifiyDatasetChanged()
        addReadLess(text, textView);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            ds.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.txt_color));
        } else {
            ds.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.txt_color));
        }
    }
};

ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, ss.length() - 10, ss.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(ss);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}

private void addReadLess(final String text, final TextView textView,int index) {


SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text + " Read Less");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
position=index;
notifiyDatasetChanged
        addReadMore(text, textView);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            ds.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.txt_color));

        } else {
            ds.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.txt_color));

        }
    }
};
ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, ss.length() - 10, ss.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(ss);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

Comment: I am not handling specific items click let me show you section of  code where methods are called in onBindViewHolder() -->     txt = list_ada.get(position).getNewsDescE();
        if (txt.length() >= 280) {
            addReadMore(txt, holder.news_des);
        } else {
            holder.news_des.setText(list_ada.get(position).getNewsDescE());
        }

Comment: You will need to keep the other variable also, for closing and opening the views. You can do something like this,
    if(length>280 && position==-1){
     //for first time, call read more
   }
  else if(length<280){
   //Call read less)
  }
else {
  //Call read more when manual clicks are done on position
}

Comment: sorry, I can't handle this, please can you post your logic.

Comment: in addReadMore(text, textView);  what index I will pass to call addReadLess(final String text, final TextView textView,int index)?

Comment: position from the bindViewHolder paramaters.

Comment: glad I could  help. :) don't forget to upvote/accept it as an answer.